# xamarin iOS ONLY Plugin.Geolocator Authorization Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I have some code that gets the geolocationposition it works in andproid but not in iOS.

In **iOS only** using the Plugin.Geolocator I get

> Location permission denied, can not get positions async. Unhandled
>   Exception: Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.GeolocationException: A
>   geolocation error occured: Unauthorized

below is what I have in the plist (removed not relevant stuff)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        etc.......

        <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Can we use your location</string>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>We are using your location</string>
        <key>RequestWhenInUseAuthorization</key>
        <string>Need location for geolocator plugin</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It's working for android so I guess cannot be code but settings.

any suggestions?

**EDIT**
Tried the sample that comes with the plugin itself and even though seems to work
i see an error in the output window. Do I need to set some settings in the emulator ? how?

> GeolocatorSampleiOS[16172:675663091] Location permission denied, can
>   not get positions async.

code I use for both android and iOS (works with android)

```cs
private async Task<Location> GetDeviceLocationAsync2()
{
    try
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
            {
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }
        }

        var currentLocation = await Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync(); 

        if (currentLocation != null)
        {
            return currentLocation;
        }

        if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
        {
            //todo
            return null;
        }

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(
                GeolocationAccuracy.Best, 
                new TimeSpan(30000))
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Best
            };

            currentLocation =await Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
            LogCurrentLocation(currentLocation);
        }
        else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
        {
            await DisplayDialogAsync("Location denied", "Do not have access to location");
        }

        return currentLocation;
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
    {
        // Handle not supported on device exception
        //todo:add logging
    }
    catch (PermissionException ex)
    {
        // Handle permission exception
        //todo:add logging
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Unable to get location
        //todo:add logging
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are you requesting permissions to use the GPS?

Comment: @Jason could you look at my question again I have edited and added the code I use for both android and iOS . Am I missing something?

Comment: if they don't grant permissions you are still attempting to set currentLocation

Comment: I see .thanks!  however does not resolve my issue ,stepping through the code i have permission but seconds later i get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I needed to set permissions in the emulator!!!